# "(lldb)" error when running my program in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am taking a course on Udemy to help learn iOS programming this winter and I am having trouble making this error go away. All the error tells me is "(lldb)" there is nothing else in the debugging box. However it does enter a break point after "if numberInt != nil {" here is my code:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var number: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var numberInt = Int(number.text!)

    if numberInt != nil {

        var unwrappedNumber = numberInt!

        var isPrime = true

        if unwrappedNumber == 1 {

            isPrime = false

        }

        if unwrappedNumber != 2 && unwrappedNumber != 1 {

            for var i = 2; i < unwrappedNumber; i++ {

                if unwrappedNumber % i == 0 {

                    isPrime = false

                }

            }

        }

        if isPrime == true {

            resultLabel.text = "\(unwrappedNumber) is prime!"

        }
        else{

            resultLabel.text = "\(unwrappedNumber) is not prime!"

        }

    }

    else
    {

        resultLabel.text = "Please enter a number in the box"

    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I am coding this in xCode and using swift not c#. This is my first time asking a question on here, I hope after some time practicing I will be able to help you guys out as well. If anyone would care to help me out learning the debugger on xCode that would be great too! Thanks, I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: what is the xcode version you're usng ?

Comment: I understand you're newbie. please refer youtube to get more see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGB22A1p6Xs)  to get more idea about debugger.

Comment: Newest Version of xCode. I am actually looking up a youtube video on debugging right now! I will take a look at yours when I am done with the one I am watching currently. Thanks! Do you have any idea why I am getting the lldb error?

Comment: BTW, you can simplify this a bit if you use "conditional binding" (using `if let` to both unwrap the optional, as well as check to see if that succeeded or not). See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/06ef1a474d15267b4b45

Comment: Great, thank you Rob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
var unwrappedNumber = numberInt!
```

to

```
var unwrappedNumber = numberInt
```

and you no need exlamation mark after you check nil

Comment: I figured it out, apparently there was a breakpoint that I did not know I added in so the program was quitting at the break point. Thanks for the help though! I'll be sure to check out the debugging video you suggested to me!

Comment: He does need the exclamation mark after checking to see if it's not `nil`, unless he did conditional binding (`if let`).